# htacces redirect if a directory is not complete

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'd like to manage a redirect by htacces when a link is incomplete. My code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^composizioni/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

A link like this https://www.site.it/composizioni/ should be redirected to a 404 page because lacks of 2nd dir.

Thanks.

Comment: What currently happens when you request `/composizioni/`? Assuming `/composizioni` is not a physical filesystem directory then you should currently be seeing a 301 redirect to remove the trailing slash, which should then result in a 404? If it is a physical directory then you are probably seeing a 403, unless there is also a directory index document in that directory?

Comment: ... The point is, that URL should already be resulting in a 404. (But I'm wondering why you have a generic rule to remove the trailing slash when you appear to only have one URL format? And why do you allow an optional trailing slash in the last rule?)

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect any link like `/composizioni/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ - [R=404,NC,L]
```